# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './types' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json

Estoy en Node.js y estoy intentando lanzar mi aplicacion con el comando **nodemon app** pero me tope con este error probe reinstalar node.js y no paso nada tambien probe cambiar de version y tampoco paso nada.Agradeceria mucho una ayuda!

Archivo package.json:

```
    {
    "name": "node",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "app.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
        "sequelize": "^6.21.2"
    }
}
```

Archivo app.js

```js
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import db from "./database/db.js"
import blogRoutes from './routes/routes.js'

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/blogs', blogRoutes)

try {
    await db.authenticate()
    console.log('DB is Connect')
} catch (error) {
    console.log('El error de conexion es: ${error}')
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('HOLA MUNDO')
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Serve UP running in http://localhost:8000/')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

debes buscar en tu código el llamado a sequelize/types y quitarlo, el error dice que no puede exportar ./types, en el codigo que estoy viendo no lo veo pero te pongo ejemplos para que los busques en tus .JS:

const { DatabaseError } = require('sequelize/types');
o
const { json } = require('sequelize/types');

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).